# App doesn't work after downloading from Google Play

Tags: android, apk, google-play

It's a UCCW app skin... The app works when I side load it, but for some reason it doesn't work if downloaded from Google Play... I tried updating it, resigned a new apk, and uploaded it to Google Play... Still doesn't work... Had two customer complaints about it today, had one complain a few weeks back... Decided to try downloading it my self, and figure out this was the problem... I also have a couple other UCCW skins, that work after downloading, they all use the same code... I rebuilt the skins, and still doesn't work... I'm not sure what the problem is... Maybe the keystore?... But if it's the keystore, how do I use a new one, to update it in Google Play...

Comment: have you tired apk file before uploading

Comment: Is there any error message ,while downloading from play store?

Comment: Yeah, like I said it works when I side load the app... I don't get any errors when downloading it from Gogle Play... It downloads like normal, but It doesn't work... I'm not sure if you are familiar with UCCW... But the app is downloaded, but when you go into the lest of installed skins in UCCW, the skins are missing...

Comment: run the signed apk on your device before deploying it on play ,so you will get an idea of exact problem

Comment: Like I said, when side loading the apk to my device, it works... All the skins show up... It's only after downloading it from Google Play, that the skins wont show up in UCCW... I re done everything... Rebuilt the skins in UCCW, added the new files to a completely new file package in eclipse... The only thing thats the same, is the package name, and the keystore...

Comment: AFAIK keystore doesnt really effect the apk in any adverse way if possible can u share the link with us.

Comment: Ok, this is what I did. I used the same files as used with the origional apk, thats not working in Google Play. I changed the package name to TEST A, and signed TEST A with the origional keystore. Uploaded it to Google Play as a new app. I then used the same file again, and changed the package name to TEST B. I signed TEST B with a new keystore. Uploaded it to Google Play as another new app... waited for both to show up in Google Play, downloaded both, both worked... So it has nothing to do with my app, it's something with Google Play... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue with a game recently, and it ended up having to do with the difference in APK encyrption in the store post-Jelly Bean. Our fix ended up being how we accessed the bundle's files:

```
// Get the API version running on the device
int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if (apiVersion >= 16) {
    // Jelly Bean or later
    Moai.mount("bundle", myApp.sourceDir);
} else {
    // pre-Jelly Bean
    Moai.mount("bundle", myApp.publicSourceDir);
}
```

Have a look at the full story [here](http://www.typeoneerror.com/articles/post/solved-android-app-not-working-only-on-google-play).

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using Google Play's signing service and if anything relies on your app's SHA hash. I had this issue with Amazon Voice Services. Everything worked fine until I used the Google Play version. It was because they were RE-SIGNING the app with their key instead of mine. I wrote an article about it that may help: https://auri.net/2021/07/29/fix-app-no-longer-works-after-uploaded-to-google-play/